# Using the same mbox file for multiple accounts

Tags: linux, email, mutt

Is it possible to use the same mbox inbox file (retrieved with getmail) to load mails from two different email accounts without causing any conflicts?

Comment: What do you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

getmail locks the mbox file during update, so that should work fine as long as you configure both retrievers that write to the same configuration for locking:

> You must ensure that all other programs accessing any the mbox file expect mboxrd-format mbox files and the same type of file locking that you configure getmail to use; failure to do so can cause mbox corruption. If you do not know what type of file locking your system expects, ask your system administrator. If you are the system administrator and don't know what type of file locking your system expects, do not use Mboxrd files; use Maildirs instead. Note that delivering to mbox files over NFS can be unreliable and should be avoided; this is the case with any MDA.

(from http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/configuration.html )

You can of course also retrieve from the accounts one after the other and not run into problems between the getmail instances.